# Install PECL Intl on MAMP 2.2 with PHP 5.5.3

Tags: php, mamp, pecl, yii2

When i installed the framework Yii2 and i verified to launch `requirements.php` for check if PHP extensions have been loaded.

[image: Requirements]

1. I installed **icu4c** using brew like :

   brew install icu4c
2. I installed **intl** using PECL like :

   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/pecl install intl

   Dir icu4c : /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/52.1/
3. In PHPInfo, i have :

[image: PHPInfo]

But in Yii2, i launched `requirements.php` and the extension **intl** is not always work.

Info : When i execute `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php -m` :

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
yaz
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

And i see not where `intl`... Is this normal ? I wonder if the problem is rather to MAMP or PECL ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

Yii Framework fixed : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that PHP on apache uses a different `php.ini` files than PHP on CLI.

Find out for CLI by running

```
$ php --ini
```

The php.ini for apache can be seen in phpinfo().

If they are different, you need to add the extension loading directive to the CLI one, too.

Also make sure to restart apache after modifying the php.ini for mod_php.

Comment: Yes, they are different. I added the extension loading to the cli and it's works. Thanks !